# how to show data from firebase into a textview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

hi I'm new at programming and i want to show my data from my firebase database into a textview. 
i have written some code but i doesn't work.
I hope you can help me

thank you

this is my code

```
public void goToAnotherActivity19(View view) {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    assert user != null;
    final String log_uid = user.getUid();
    final String Eintrag = eintragTagebuch.getText().toString().trim();
    Intent Intent = new Intent(this, Tagebuch.class);
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("User" + log_uid);
    myRef.child("Tagebuch").push().setValue("Ihr Eintrag: " +  Eintrag );
    startActivity(Intent);
    eingabeAusgeben();

}
    public void eingabeAusgeben() {
        tagebuchText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagebuch_text2);

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        assert user != null;
        final String log_uid = user.getUid();
        DatabaseReference tagebuchRef = rootRef.child("User"+log_uid).child("Tagebuch");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {


            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.e("TAG", value + ", ");
                    tagebuchText.setText("Deine Einträge" + value);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        tagebuchRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }
```

Comment: any error message you can share?

Comment: If you want (quicker) answers, you should add your code language into the tags.

Comment: hi, i don't have any error message, 
it is running but in the textView nothing is shown
thank you for the information with the tags

Comment: 09-14 10:43:58.927 2642-3517/com.example.mac.insulin W/SyncTree: Listen at /UseriV0Z5txfgBQdCdYFf1l95WLCFiV2/Tagebuch failed: DatabaseError: This client does not have permission to perform this operation


this is my error message